# How to stop CapeDwarf JBoss AS7 from storing logs in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-datastore, capedwarf

I am using CapeDwarf JBoss AS7 to host classic GAE+GWT application. On server side, I am logging directly to java.util.Logger framework.

The application works fine, the logs print nice to the console and files.

However, all my logs, together with some http request logs, are also stored in the datastore. Yes, every log line becomes one datastore entity. This should not surprise me, because it is stated in the docs (http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf/docs) and it is needed in order to display logs in gae-like admin console of CapeDwarf.

I was looking for a way to disable this useful but expensive feature. I cannot find any docs that would tell me what to do if I do not need/want my logs in the datastore (e.g. right now 98.3% of my datastore are __org.jboss.capedwarf.LogRequest__ and __org.jboss.capedwarf.LogLine__ entities!). Does anyone happen to know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered on our forum: https://community.jboss.org/message/810735#810735